# Why is a space missing in the result of git diff --color-words?

Tags: git

result of `git diff` =>

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 064858a..31140d8 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-There is a problem.
+There is problem.
```

result of `git diff --color-words` =>

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 064858a..31140d8 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
There isa problem.
```

Why is it "There isa problem." and not "There is a problem."? A space is missing.

Comment: Maybe because of a bug in git? Try reporting it.

Comment: Or perhaps your terminal is not rendering the escape sequences that highlight the changes in colour correctly?

Comment: True, kind of unexpected, but maybe because whitespaces are ignored for words by design (not sure if I interpret https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diff-regexltregexgt correctly)? `--color-words` already implies the `--word-diff` option with the default built-in "words" regex (if I understand how it all works).

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior of `git word-diff` in any shell. If you remove a word in the middle of a line, it will not show the leading whitespace. You could have any number of spaces between `is` and `problem` in your original text, and the output would be the same.

`git diff --color-words` is the same as [git word-diff=color](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-color).

Without specifying a custom regex, word-diff is only capable of showing you differences in runs of non-whitespace characters. As per the docs, the "output may be ambiguous" when there are changes made to the whitespace.

To get a better understanding of how this output works, try running it as `git word-diff=plain`.

If you look at this [readme for the library gitwdiff](https://github.com/suomela/gitwdiff), you can see a comparison between the outputs of a standard `git word-diff` and their version `gitwdiff`. It clearly shows that removed words in `word-diff` do not render the whitespace change.

`wdiff` is a more specialized command-line utility for diffing words, and it shows the output with the expected whitespace, so you may prefer that.